# Fill dataframe with zeroes

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe looking as such :

```
A    B    C
a    1    3
a    2    5
a    4    3
b    1    2
b    2    6
    ...
```

And I want to add a row  `l   i   0` for each l in A and i in {1, 2, 3, 4} such that there is no `l    i    k` row existing.

For this example, if I consideer {1, 2, 3, 4}, the result would be

```
A    B    C
a    1    3
a    2    5
a    3    0
a    4    3
b    1    2
b    2    6
b    3    0
b    4    0
    ...
```

I felt like I could use a dataframe containing `1 2 3 4`, and try to full_join but I don't see how to manage that.

How to get this result ?

Comment: It is unclear exactly what you are trying to achieve. Can you provide a small example output of what you want?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I added the result wanted for the example I gave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enumerate all combinations of column A and B using `expand.grid`, then remove all pairs already present in the original data frame using `sigdiff` from `dplyr` and add a zero-column.

```
library(dplyr)

D <- read.table(header=TRUE, text = "
A    B    C
a    1    3
a    2    5
a    4    3
b    1    2
b    2    6
")

expand.grid(A=unique(D$A), B=1:4) %>%
  setdiff(D[,1:2]) %>%
  mutate(C=0) %>%
  bind_rows(D) %>%
  arrange(A, B)

#>   A B C
#> 1 a 1 3
#> 2 a 2 5
#> 3 a 3 0
#> 4 a 4 3
#> 5 b 1 2
#> 6 b 2 6
#> 7 b 3 0
#> 8 b 4 0
```

Answer (score 3):

By using `complete`

```
df %>% complete(B = full_seq(B, 1), A,fill=list(C=0))%>%arrange(A)
# A tibble: 8 x 3
      B     A     C
  <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
1     1     a     3
2     2     a     5
3     3     a     0
4     4     a     3
5     1     b     2
6     2     b     6
7     3     b     0
8     4     b     0
```